# Permission denied (publickey) on EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

So I was making some changes in my ssh folder of my EC2 instance, but after a while I got disconnected and when trying to log in again, I couldn't because of files moved inside ssh folder. So I went through detaching my volume, attaching it to another instance, adding the new authorized_keys file and reattaching to my original instance, but still no luck. I have other instances that use the same key file and can connect with no problem, but not on this instance, and I know it is the correct key because if I try to connect with root user I get this

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/luis/.ssh/EC2_private.key': 
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

So ir is succeeding but because it's root it asks me to connect with ubuntu user, but with ubuntu it shows me this:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/luis/.ssh/EC2_private.key': 
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I assume it has to do with permissions, but I already checked, and I do have 700 in my ssh folder and 600 in my authorized_keys.

So I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the permissions I had to set were 750 in my ssh folder instead of 700, anyway I don't know why I got downvoted, at least give a reason.

Comment: It wasn't me. But I'd say it's because you showed very little research effort. Your ssh log would have told you what the problem was. There are several other things you could have tried as well e.g. login as a different user, enable root logins, compare directory/file permissions between users, etc... just to name a few. You also didn't provide much for us to go on in order to try an help you. We could not have caught the permissions error, because you provided the wrong information, didn't provide an `ls -l` or anything and didn't check the logs. Please don't take offence.